# How can I use ADOX components in Delphi XE4?

Tags: database, delphi, adox

I read in a tutorial written to Delphi 6 : to install ADOX components, select from the main menu Project\Add type Library menu item. But in Delphi XE4 there is not such a menu item. How could I install/use ADOX components in Delphi XE4 to create an empty mdb database programatically? Or is there any other way to create it without ADOX?

Comment: Pardon my curiousity, but what are you wanting to do with ADOX that can't be done using Delphi's ADO components?

Comment: [which at one point were moved to the `dbGo` component tab]
.

Comment: @MartynA, ADOX catalog for example. or creating an empty mdb file using it.

Comment: @MartynA I want to do what i have written. Creating an empty mdb file just programatically (without any ODBC wizard interaction). But as I wrote I interrested in any alternatve way as well if you explain it for me.

Comment: It appears everything ADOX does is something ADO can already do - it just makes it a little easier.

Comment: @JerryDodge, Can you create an empty MDB database file with ADO?

Comment: @kobik I thought that's exactly what you're demonstrating in your answer? [Correction] Nope, I was mis-lead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use late binding without importing the type library e.g.:

```
uses ComObj;

procedure CreateNewMDB(const FileName: WideString);
var
  AdoX: OleVariant;
begin
  AdoX := CreateOleObject('ADOX.Catalog');
  AdoX.Create('Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Data Source=' + FileName);
end;
```

If this is all you need, I think it's not worth the effort of importing the ADOX type library.

Comment: What unit should I include into the uses section for the createOLEObject function?

Comment: You need to add `uses ComObj;`

Comment: Whatever tutorial you were already reading should already be covering these things, including how to acquire the DLL you need, right?

Comment: Thx for your ansver Kobik. It created the mdb file despite the adox component wasn't in the type library list (msadox*.dll not found by default)

Answer (score 1):

`Add type library` was an option in older versions of Delphi. In more modern versions, go to `Component > Import Component` instead, where it has the option to `Import a Type Library`.

Comment: Thx for the info. I tried it but the import dlg default list does not contain ADOX. Where can I download msadox.dll for Delphi XE4 from?

Comment: @TheBitman Well that's a whole different question. Refer back to the tutorial you were already reading.

Comment: Or which version of msadox.dll needed for DXE4?

Comment: You may very well already have it.  On Win 10, there are several copies in different places including c:\program files\common files\ado - there is an msadox28.tlb in that folder, too.

Comment: And it's not necessarily a matter of getting the version needed for your Delphi version. But instead, the version which supports the capabilities you desire. Usually, that means the latest version you can find.

Comment: @MartynA I have Win7 64

Comment: And?  I have Win7 64 in a VM and that has the same adox files in the same places.  I have never wittingly installed them on any machine I use. If you haven't already, do a `dir msadox*.* /s > dump.txt & notepad dump.txt` from a c:\ prompt.

Comment: @MartynA The dir command found it in : "c:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado" folder. Thx for your ansvers/propounds.